# Aggregating one bigquery table to another bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to aggregate multi PB (around 7PB) worth of BigQuery Table into another BigQuery Table

I have `(partition_key, clusterkey1, clusterkey2, col1, col2, val)`

Where `partition_key` is used for bigquery partition and `clusterkey` is used for clustering.

For example

```
(timestamp1, timestamp2, 0, 1, 2, 1)

(timestamp3, timestamp4, 0, 1, 2, 7)

(timestamp31, timestamp22, 2, 1, 2, 2)

(timestamp11, timestamp12, 2, 1, 2, 3)
```

should result to

```
(0, 1, 2, 8)

(2, 1, 2, 5)
```

I want to aggregate base on `(clusterkey2, col1, col2)`, across all `partition_key` and all `clusterkey1` for val

What is a feasible way to do this?

Should I write a custom loader and just read all data from it line by line, or is there a native way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where / how you are executing this you can do it by writing a simple sql script and defining the target output, for example:

```
SELECT clusterkey2
     , col1
     , col2
     , sum(val)
from table
group by clusterkey2, col1, col2
```

This will get you the desired results.

From here you can do a few things, but they are mostly all outlined here in the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#writing_query_results

Specifically from the above you are looking to set the destination table.

[image]

One thing to note, you may want to include a partition key in the where clause to help narrow down your data if you do not want the aggregate results of the whole table.

Comment: I need to aggregate the entire bq table to another bq table, can big query web browser handle such a large data like this?

Comment: Yes because it won't return the whole data to your browser, just the first 1000 rows.  You can also embed that query in a bq command or python script and execute it somewhere else.  The important part is you will want to specify the output using something like a CREATE AS, the query options in the gui, or the destination table flag in the bq command

Comment: One more add, you may want to check to see how much data the query will process before hand.  If you are on-demand pricing it may be fairly expensive.

Comment: The size of the table is about 7PB i don't mind running the query in gcp browser console OR using a python script as long as it is async ( i can submit the query and don't need to keep the terminal open), do you know if that is possible?

Comment: Both the python client and UI create the job asynchronous https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob